# Opening one form from another form and closing original form from command click

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I have created a log in form that when the "Open Database" button is clicked opens another form. I am trying to get the original form "UserInformation" to close when the button is clicked to open the other form. I am trying all kinds of VBA code and nothing seems to be working. I created the button through the wizard and then converted the macro to vba code.

```
Private Sub cmdOpenDatabase_Click()

If IsNull(Me.txtFirstName) Then
MsgBox ("Please enter First Name")
Me.txtFirstName.SetFocus
Cancel = True
Exit Sub
End If

If IsNull(Me.txtLastName) Then
MsgBox ("Please enter Last Name")
Me.txtLastName.SetFocus
Cancel = True
Exit Sub
End If

If IsNull(Me.txtEmployee) Then
MsgBox ("Please enter Employee ID")
Me.txtEmployee.SetFocus
Cancel = True
Exit Sub
End If

On Error GoTo cmdOpenDatabase_Click_Err

    DoCmd.OpenForm "Standards", acNormal, "", "", , acNormal

cmdOpenDatabase_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

cmdOpenDatabase_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume cmdOpenDatabase_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call `DoCmd.Close` for the current form (`Me.Name`) after you call `DoCmd.OpenForm` to open the other form.  Note *acNormal* is not a supported value for the `OpenForm` *WindowMode* option; I guessed you want *acWindowNormal* there instead.

```vb
'DoCmd.OpenForm "Standards", acNormal, "", "", , acNormal
DoCmd.OpenForm "Standards", acNormal, , , , acWindowNormal
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
```

Also consider whether including the option names makes your code easier to understand:

```vb
DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="Standards", View:=acNormal, WindowMode:=acWindowNormal
DoCmd.Close ObjectType:=acForm, ObjectName:=Me.Name
```

Finally, `Cancel = True` does not accomplish anything in a command button click event procedure.  In fact, with `Option Explicit` in your form module's Declarations section, `Cancel` will trigger a compile error (*"Variable not defined"*) there.  And as standard practice, you should include `Option Explicit` in all your code modules.

Here is an alternate version of your procedure ...

```vb
Private Sub cmdOpenDatabase_Click()
    Dim blnMissingData As Boolean

    If IsNull(Me.txtFirstName) Then
        MsgBox "Please enter First Name"
        Me.txtFirstName.SetFocus
        blnMissingData = True
    End If

    If IsNull(Me.txtLastName) Then
        MsgBox "Please enter Last Name"
        Me.txtLastName.SetFocus
        blnMissingData = True
    End If

    If IsNull(Me.txtEmployee) Then
        MsgBox "Please enter Employee ID"
        Me.txtEmployee.SetFocus
        blnMissingData = True
    End If

    On Error GoTo cmdOpenDatabase_Click_Err

    If Not blnMissingData Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="Standards", View:=acNormal, WindowMode:=acWindowNormal
        DoCmd.Close ObjectType:=acForm, ObjectName:=Me.Name
    End If

cmdOpenDatabase_Click_Exit:
        Exit Sub

cmdOpenDatabase_Click_Err:
        MsgBox Error$
        Resume cmdOpenDatabase_Click_Exit
End Sub
```